# equation $\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

- Frist I solved this equation $\displaystyle \frac{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}}{\frac{1}{xy}}$ by multiplying $xy \left(\frac{xy}{x}+\frac{xy}{y}\right)=y+x$ The answer is correct.
- Next equation was:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}}$$

I made the bottom multiplied and got $x^2 y^2.$ So I made the up also multiply and got

$$\frac{\frac{y^2}{x^2}-\frac{x^2}{y^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2y^2}}.$$ 
 Now I'm stuck.

So now I doubt I did the first one the right way. I might have gotten the answer right but not the correct way to get it. Im sorry if Im confusing. Can someone help me with the two were I go wrong?

Comment: Is it $a-b/c+d$ or $\frac{a-b}{c+d}?$

Comment: The last one that your typed.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't see you working with an equation, but rather you seem to be working with an expression. It would help if you wrote **exactly** what the question was, without leaving out any words or symbols. As it now stands, I am not sure what you are asking. Do you want to know how to reduce a certain algebraic expression to lowest terms? If so, which expression?

Comment: What is the reason to multiply by $x^2y^2?$

Comment: it asks for simplify.

Comment: is my approach for first one correct?

Comment: But this is useful in your example, since you are dividing by $1/xy,$ that is the same to multiply by $xy.$ In the other case, work the numerator and denominator separately and get it back together.

Answer (score 3):

You have

$$\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{x^2y^2}$$

and

$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}=\frac{y^2+x^2}{x^2y^2}$$

So

$$\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}}=\frac{\frac{y^2-x^2}{x^2y^2}}{\frac{y^2+x^2}{x^2y^2}}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{y^2+x^2}$$

Comment: So I can solve separate and then get it back together. The undersides are same so I can stripe it away. Thanks I get it.

Comment: Is my approach for first one correct? You asked why I multiply by xy. I wanted to get it simpler by dividing xy after

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't have equations to solve (no equal sign), you have expressions you are trying to simplify.  When you multiplied the denominator by $x^2y^2$ you should have $x^2y^2(\frac 1{x^2}+\frac 1{y^2})=y^2+x^2$  When you multiply the numerator you should have $x^2y^2(\frac 1{x^2}-\frac 1{y^2})=y^2-x^2$, giving a final answer of $\frac {y^2-x^2}{y^2+x^2}$

Answer (score 1):

hint:
multiply numerator and denominator by $x^2y^2$