# Simplify: $\displaystyle\frac{\frac{a}{x}-\frac{a}{y}}{\frac{a}{x}+\frac{a}{y}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify: $\displaystyle\frac{\frac{a}{x}-\frac{a}{y}}{\frac{a}{x}+\frac{a}{y}}$

I did $\displaystyle\frac{ay}{xy}-\frac{ax}{xy}=y-x$ on top in underside.
I did $\displaystyle\frac{ay}{xy}+\frac{ax}{xy}=ay+ax=a(y+x)$.

My final answer is $\displaystyle\frac{y-x}{ay+ax}$. Is this correct?

I posted question before but now just bit different. Please explain in steps so I understand this form and solve my other problems.

Comment: You have $\frac{a}{x}-\frac{a}{y}=\frac{ay}{xy}-\frac{ax}{xy}=\frac{ay-ax}{xy}.$ Your simplification is not correct. In the second part you have omitted the denominator.

Comment: thanks I think I got the hang of this form now.

Comment: @mfl, I wish I could give you +1 for the heroic task of editing this question! :)

Comment: Note that this is the same as [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860381/equation-frac-frac1x2-frac1y2-frac1x2-frac1y2) except both numerator and denominator have been multiplied by $a$.  The answer is the same.

Answer (score 5):

Since $\dfrac ax+\dfrac ay=\dfrac {ay+ax}{xy}$ we get

$$\frac {\frac ax-\frac ay}{\frac ax+\frac ay}\\
=\frac{\frac{ay-ax}{xy}}{\frac{ay+ax}{xy}}=\frac{ay-ax}{ay+ax}$$

Further, there is the common factor $a$, so it can be reduced to

$$y-x\over y+x$$

This is nearly as simple as the expression gets, it could also be written as

$${y-x\over y+x}={2y\over y+x}-1=1+{2x\over y+x}$$

Comment: or $1+\frac{2}{1\,+\,y\,/\,x}$

Answer (score 2):

The expression is undefined if any of $a$, $x$, or $y$ is $0$. So assuming all three of these are nonzero, then you have $$\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{a}{x}-\frac{a}{y}}{\frac{a}{x}+\frac{a}{y}}&=
\frac{\frac{a}{x}-\frac{a}{y}}{\frac{a}{x}+\frac{a}{y}}\cdot\frac{xy}{xy}\\
&=\frac{ay-ax}{ay+ax}\\
&=\frac{a(y-x)}{a(y+x)}\\
&=\frac{y-x}{y+x}
\end{align}$$